# .htaccess allow one specific file format only in directory listing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file-type

I have a directory but only want one file type to be listed.

I've tried the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?!ext).*$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

However it gives me a 403.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [IndexIgnore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) directive

> The IndexIgnore directive adds to the
>   list of files to hide when listing a
>   directory. File is a shell-style
>   wildcard expression or full filename.
>   Multiple IndexIgnore directives add to
>   the list, rather than the replacing
>   the list of ignored files. By default,
>   the list contains . (the current
>   directory).
>
> ```
> IndexIgnore README .htaccess *.bak *~
> ```